# Accessing alternate clipboard formats from python

Tags: python, windows, macos, tkinter, clipboard

Copying to the clipboard from an application that supports rich text will typically add the text in several formats. I need to find out the available formats, and then retrieve the clipboard contents in a selected format. In case it matters, I'm interested in rich text formats (from Word, Acrobat, browsers, ...), not in image data or other [exotica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5016874/699305).

I've looked and looked, but the solutions I've found are limited to plain text, [super outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101167/699305), specific to Windows (I'm on OS X), [reliant](http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/) on the commandline utilities `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` (which don't handle all clipboard formats), or several of the above.

**So:** How can I get a list of the formats present in the clipboard, and extract its contents in a format of my choice?

Platforms, in order of interest: system-independent (I wish), OS X Mountain Lion (my current platform) or similar, other platforms (I plan to distribute my code).

#### Selected links

[pyperclip](http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/): Looks interesting, but on OS X it delegates to `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` which support `text`, `rtf` and `ps` formats only.

[This recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/474121-getting-html-from-the-windows-clipboard/) from activestate is for Windows only, but shows how to get HTML. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17298897/699305) SO question refers to it).

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101167/699305) is also specific to win32clipboard.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5016874/699305) question is about dragging and dropping files to the clipboard (on Windows). Interesting, but no help with what I need.

[This tkinter-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9630235) is simple and still works on OS X, but it only gets plain text-- and I've found no evidence that tkinter can handle anything else.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4203897/699305) shows near-identical tkinter code for *putting* text on the clipboard.

#### Edit (May 2017)

I now have a solution for OS X (see [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43915933/699305) below), but I would appreciate hearing if (and how) `pyperclip` or another module can do the same on Windows. Pyperclip gets its hands deep in the Windows API, so it can't be very far from supporting a listing and selection of all available formats.

Comment: Related question: [linux - getting HTML source or rich text from the X clipboard - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261379/getting-html-source-or-rich-text-from-the-x-clipboard), [html - How to send rich text to the clipboard from command line? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/912712/how-to-send-rich-text-to-the-clipboard-from-command-line) (nothing Python-specific though, but have solutions for Windows and X/Linux as well)

Comment: Thank you, those are interesting links. But they are 8 and 13 years old, so probably qualify as "super outdated". I was not able to test the glib/gtk solution since brew does not know gtk, my mac does not have python2, and i didn't bother any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite straightforward on OS X with the help of the module [richxerox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/richxerox), available on pypi. It requires system support including the Apple `AppKit` and `Foundation` modules. I had trouble building Objective C for Python 3, so that initially I had only gotten this to work for Python 2. Anaconda 3 comes with all the necessary pieces preinstalled, however.

Here's a demo that prints the available clipboard types, and then fetches and prints each one:

```
import richxerox as rx

# Dump formats
verbose = True
if verbose:
        print(rx.available(neat=False, dyn=True))
    else:
        print(rx.available())

# Dump contents in all formats
for k, v in rx.pasteall(neat=False, dyn=True).items():
    line = "\n*** "+k+":  "+v
    print(line)
```

**Output:**

```
(
    "public.html",
    "public.utf8-plain-text"
)

*** public.html:  <html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head><body><a href="http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/" 
  rel="nofollow noreferrer">pyperclip</a>: Looks interesting</body></html>

*** public.utf8-plain-text:  pyperclip: Looks interesting
```

To print in a desired format with fall-back to text, you could use this:

```
paste_format = "rtf"
content = rx.paste(paste_format)
if not content:
    content = rx.paste("text")
```

Or you could first check if a format is available:

```
if "public.rtf" in rx.available():
    content = rx.paste("rtf")
else:
    content = rx.paste("text")
```